# Is this poset shellable?

Tags: posets

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over a finite field $F$. (The case $F = \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is the case I most care about.)  Consider the poset of linearly independent subsets of $V$ ordered by inclusion. Is this poset shellable? There is an obvious lexicographic ordering that might be of use.

Comment: shellable? lol why is that a thing. you may want to define that for myself and others.

Comment: _shellable:_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shelling_(topology)

Comment: @DouglasSirk Add to Carlo Bennaker's wikipedia link that a poset is called shellable iff its order complex is shellable.

Comment: The collection of linearly independent subsets of $V$ ordered by inclusion is naturally a simplicial complex (indeed, it is evidently the independence complex of a matroid realizable over your field $F$). Do you want perhaps to know if this independence complex is shellable? Asking if the *poset* of faces is shellable is the same as asking if the barycentric subdivision of this independence complex is shellable?

Comment: But to answer your question: the independence complex of any matroid is shellable- see Björner "The homology and shellability of matroids and geometric lattices"; and barycentric subdivision preserves shellability- see Björner "Shellable and Cohen-Macaulay Partially Ordered Sets".

Comment: @SamHopkins  It would be good to post your comments as an answer, so that the system doesn't think the question is unanswered.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: done.

Answer (score 7):

(Upgrading comments to an answer.)

The collection of linearly independent subsets of a finite-dimensional vector space $V$ over a finite field $F$ ordered by inclusion is naturally a finite simplicial complex: it is evidently the independence complex of a matroid realizable over $F$.

You might actually want to know if this independence complex is shellable. Asking if the *poset of faces* is shellable is the same as asking if the *barycentric subdivision* of this independence complex is shellable.

At any rate: the independence complex of any (finite) matroid is shellable: see Björner, "The homology and shellability of matroids and geometric lattices" (citation below). And moreover,  barycentric subdivision preserves shellability: see Björner, "Shellable and Cohen-Macaulay partially ordered sets".

Hence, whatever your intended question, the answer is: yes, this complex is shellable.

*Björner, Anders*, [**Shellable and Cohen-Macaulay partially ordered sets**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/1999881), Trans. Am. Math. Soc. 260, 159-183 (1980). [ZBL0441.06002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0441.06002).

*Björner, Anders*, The homology and shellability of matroids and geometric lattices, Matroid applications, Encycl. Math. Appl. 40, 226-283 (1992). [ZBL0772.05027](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0772.05027).

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you.

Comment: (You can accept the answer if it’s what you want.)

Comment: (By the way, an issue I’m slightly eliding is that when discussing the topology of a poset with a minimal element- in this case, the empty set, or empty face- it is conventional to omit this minimal element when taking the order complex: otherwise the complex you get is always contractile, as it is a cone. In order for “order complex of face poset=barcentryic subdivision of original complex” to be true you have to do this removal of the empty face.)

Comment: I think the empty set is considered linearly independent; it amounts to augmenting the simplicial complex. A maximum element would be adding a cone point.

Comment: I’m saying: if you naively take the order complex of a poset with a minimum (or with a maximum) you will get a complex that’s a cone (hence in particular necessarily contractible).