# Topology of independence set of a vector space

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, simplicial-complexes, matroid-theory

This seems like something that would have a well-known treatment somewhere, but I'm not sure where to look. If we have a vector space $V$ (or maybe even a module), we can consider an abstract simplicial complex whose $k$-simplices are collections of $k+1$ rank-$1$ subspaces such that their span is rank $k$. There are evident face maps.

It seems to me like the topology of such a natural construction is probably well-studied and understood (are they often/always contractible? if not, what are the homology groups?), but looking into the literature I got quite confused. What are the relevant results, and where can I look for an understanding of such constructions?

Comment: Should basically be the same as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/339382/is-this-poset-shellable/339395

Comment: Looking in the literature will probably become more helpful if you start with the notion of a realizable matroid, which will already bring you very close to the things you are interested in.